# problem with splash screen - C# - VS2005

Tags: c#, winforms, splash-screen

I have an application.

First I display a splash screen, a form, and this splash would call another form.

Problem: When the splash form is displayed, if I then open another application on the top of the splash, and then minimize this newly opened application window, the splash screen becomes white. How do I avoid this? I want my splash to be displayed clearly and not affected by any application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to display the splash screen in a different thread - currently your new form loading code is blocking the splash screen's UI thread.

Start a new thread, and on that thread create your splash screen and call `Application.Run(splash)`. That will start a new message pump on that thread. You'll then need to make your main UI thread call back to the splash screen's UI thread (e.g. with Control.Invoke/BeginInvoke) when it's ready, so the splash screen can close itself.

The important thing is to make sure that you don't try to modify a UI control from the wrong thread - only use the one the control was created on.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's rather complicated for beginners. I was sure there was some library or something that did that?

Comment: I don't know of anything in the framework. There may be third party libraries to make it easier.

Answer (score 3):

The .NET framework has excellent built-in support for splash screens.  Start a new WF project, Project + Add Reference, select Microsoft.VisualBasic.  Add a new form, call it frmSplash.  Open Project.cs and make it look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
  static class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      new MyApp().Run(args);
    }
  }
  class MyApp : WindowsFormsApplicationBase {
    protected override void OnCreateSplashScreen() {
      this.SplashScreen = new frmSplash();
    }
    protected override void OnCreateMainForm() {
      // Do your time consuming stuff here...
      //...
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
      // Then create the main form, the splash screen will close automatically
      this.MainForm = new Form1();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do i access a label control in my splashform inside the OnCreateMainForm method to show the use what is being loaded currently in the background ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue you might want to check out.  The [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916/multi-threaded-splash-screen-in-c) I got worked perfectly for me - you may want to take a look.