# Invoke or begininvoke cannot be called on a control which is not yet created

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a normal `Windows Forms` app, but get the following error:

```
Invoke or begininvoke cannot be called on a control which is not yet created.
```

This happens within the following code:

```
Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

var args = new string[0];

new MyApp().Run(args);
```

I am using a splash screen, which I think is where the problems started.

***How is this resolved?***

Comment: This code fragment isn't very useful and isn't complete, want to try again on that?

Comment: if you take the `new MyApp().Run(args)` line out, that should solve the problem; or to be a bit more helpful, what @Lazarus said

Comment: Yes, that's where it probably started.  Not posting that code == no solution.  Use the built-in .NET support for splash screens instead of cooking your own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392864/c-splash-screen-problem/393870#393870

Answer (score 1):

Why are you passing arguments to your own application? The default entry point definition for a `Windows Forms` application does not accept any arguments, so have you altered this manually?

Addressing what seems to be your problem, though, try using this instead:

```
Application.Run(new YourMainForm());
```

So, ultimately:

```
Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

Application.Run(new YourMainForm());
```

In order to retrieve the arguments passed to the application by the executer you can use the `Environment` class which exposes the `GetCommandLineArgs` method. So should you need to determine these values you can either A) call this method, parse and then store in a strongly typed format by means of properties or something similiar, or, B) call this method, parsing on demand, say, from within your form.

Comment: The reason for that line, is that is how the splash screen is invoked.

Comment: Isn't your splash-screen a `Form`? Start the application with a `new` splash screen form instance.

Comment: I did just try that, but what's the best way to close it and show the mainform? I can't get a reliabile transition, they seem to both close etc.

Comment: Well, it's hard to give you an ideal solution since I don't know your project and there is limited time and space available here, but one way is to have your splash-screen do whatever it needs to do to load before loading the main form; another way is to load the main form initially, show the splash screen, hide the main form, hide the splash screen and re-show the main form - all timed appropriately, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

An old post that I've just hit - it appears there is an MS bug that rears its head, almost randomly it seems, though some machines seem to be worse affected than others.

Thanks to [Mr Gallagher](http://pjgcreations.blogspot.com.au/2012/10/windows-forms-app-with-splash-screen.html) for pointing me at the [MSDN social article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/bdc00055-338d-4a4a-a881-14b242b83b83/invoke-or-begininvoke-cannot-be-called-on-a-control-until-the-window-handle-has-been-created?forum=winforms) with the work-around.

The trick is to help the Framework realise when the splash screen is actually available by not letting it hide the splash until it's been properly created.

So add a `SplashLoadFinished` flag as a user setting or similar.

Then set this flag in the Splash `Form.Load` event (the lines below must be the first and last lines respectively):

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    My.Settings.SplashLoadFinished = False
    ...
    My.Settings.SplashLoadFinished = True
End Sub
```

Then put a wait loop in the `ApplicationEvents` `Startup` event :

```vb
Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
...
If (Me.SplashScreen IsNot Nothing) Then
    'Wait until the Splash has actually been created
    While (Not My.Settings.SplashLoadFinished)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
    End While
End If
...
```