# What isn't available to me before calling Application.Run() in a standard WinForms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to do some initialization of various things at runtime of my WinForms application. I'm looking specifically at the `Program.cs` file that every WinForm application has. In it, I see:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new frmMain());
}
```

I know that this is what starts up the application and creates the initial form (in my case, an instance of `frmMain`).

Can I not just put my initialization code **before** `Application.Run()`? The initialization I need to do is to check a few registry entries, create them if necessary, and connect to a database. Will any feature not be available to my instantiation code if I put it before `Application.Run()`?

Comment: I've performed database operations before `Application.Run(form)` without harm.

Comment: That's good news! I have a little form I use as a progress indicator. This form will be the first thing the user sees, as the application is starting up. Usually what I would do is create an invisible form that is the first to load. This form then in turn creates the generic progress form and does the loading. But, initialization in `Program.cs` is much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **Windows Forms application** starts when the `Main` method is called. You can implement initialization procedures on the `Main` function. However, to initialize a **Windows Forms application** fully and start it routing **Windows Forms events**, you need to invoke `Application.Run`.

---

Read about [Application](http://en.csharp-online.net/Application_Architecture_in_Windows_Forms_2.0%E2%80%94Application)

Comment: Aha! I can call `Application.Run()` without a form or context as a parameter. Then, I can perform initialization. Doing this after the call to `Run` allows forms that I create during initialization to be interacted with, if necessary. Finally, I can manually create my main form and display it.

Comment: In this way even if you closed your main form, your application will still running until you explicitly call Application.Exit()

Comment: Oh, then maybe I should just stick with initializing before `Application.Run()`... either way, I'll have to experiment.

Answer (score 4):

`Application.Run()` starts message loop for your main thread. SO before that line of code you can do anything except what is dependent on windows messages (click, keyup, ...)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, no problem, the code in Main() is boilerplate but not cast in stone.

Do keep in mind that any code you run before calling Application.Run() will delay the startup of your user interface.  Once that goes over a second or two, give or take, you might want to consider displaying a splash screen so that the user gets some visual feedback that your program got started.  Well supported by the .NET framework, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392864/c-splash-screen-problem/393870#393870).

Comment: Good point, thanks. I'll create a splash screen, or maybe just use my progress dialog, in conjunction with my comment under Akram Shahda's answer.

Answer (score 2):

One important thing you don't have available before `Run` is a valid `SynchronizationContext.Current`. So if you use any kind of event-based asynchronous pattern components, they'll *seem* to work just fine, but will fire their events on a thread pool thread instead of the GUI thread.

Because of this, any asynchronous startup code that queues completion events to the GUI should be started from an event, not before `Run`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't need to access anything declared in `frmMain` you *should* be OK.

However [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run.aspx) states:

> Begins running a standard application message loop on the current thread.

so you won't have access to the message loop.

There is another overload [`Application.Run(ApplicationContext)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901.aspx) that will let you execute code before your form is displayed - this appears to be the way to go.

The example code on this page does some initialisation before showing two forms, so you should be OK with your model.

Comment: Interesting. What if I created a new instance of frmMain in my initialization code, and then passed it to `Application.Run()`?

Comment: @SimpleCoder - I think you can do that. Not tried it myself though.

Comment: Just tried it, and it worked. The only problem with this approach is that I can't cleanly exit the application if an error occurs. `Application.Exit()` doesn't work, because `Run` hasn't been called yet. I think creating my own  `ApplicationContext` class is the way to go. Thank you!

Comment: Found that I can use `Environment.Exit(0)` in place of `Application.Run()`.