# How to display Welcome Screen in Winform?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am doing win form project.(C#). In that project i am willing to add welcome screen. So i created a welcome screen. But, It want to show a few minitute and automatically closed and open login screen.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
            LogIn n = new LogIn();
            n.Show();
```

I try this code in form shown,load, activate events. BUt no use. Any one know what to do?.

[image: My welcome screen -]

Comment: A few minutes?  Don't forget the uninstaller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Splash Screen Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392864/c-splash-screen-problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's a tutorial](http://crazorsharp.blogspot.com/2009/06/creating-splash-screen-in-net-with.html) explaining how to make a splash screen.

Comment: Thanks. Iam using a thered to display the Splach Screen.   Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoSplash));
            th.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            th.Abort();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

Answer (score 2):

Add a line for splash screen in Program.cs. Run a timer in splash screen and close the form.

> private static void Main()
>           {
>
> ```
>         Application.EnableVisualStyles();
>
>         Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
>         Application.Run(new FSplash()); // This is your splash form << added
>         Application.Run(new FMain());
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you cannot create a splash screen in .NET for a .NET application:

The purpose of a splash screen is to distract users from long waiting times, until the application has been loaded, started and initialized.

Since a .NET application itself already has some startup time, there is no splash screen available within this time.

**My solution**

So in my applications, I am doing it the following way:

1. Write a small, tiny native C++ application.
2. Display a topmost bitmap (window with no borders) when the C++ application starts.
3. Let the C++ application start the actual .NET application.
4. The .NET application starts and when it is finished starting and initializing, it tells the C++ application to close. This is done through [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

The **inter-process communication** is done the following way:

1. The C++ application writes a temporary file.
2. When calling the .NET application, the file name is passed as a command line parameter.
3. The C++ application polls regularly whether the file exists.
4. The .NET application deletes the file as soon as the splash screen has to be hidden.
5. The C++ application exists as soon as the temporary file does not exists anymore (or a timeout occurs).

I know this is not 100% perfect, it was the most suitable solution I came up since I started developing .NET applications, years ago.

Comment: He can do this when he know C++.

Comment: Your opinion would be wrong.  Its a simple task to create a splash screen in any of the languages within the .NET Framework.  Your approach is both overkill and well just plain wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound for your balanced comment.