# Windows Forms Control Not Showing Up

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I'm trying to create a loading screen in my Windows Forms application (written in C++). I create a class "LoadingScreen" which adds a label to itself in its constructor. I then create an instance of it and call Show(). When I run the application, the form displays except the control appears as a transparent gap in the form.

Any ideas why this is?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Also, when I try the same code in another application it works. My main application splits the code across a header and a source file. Is it possible this is where my error is?

Comment: The typical problem with a "loading screen" is that your code is busy loading something and not getting around to painting the window.  Use the built-in support for splash screens in .NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392864/c-sharp-splash-screen-problem/393870#393870

Comment: I'm not having the problem when the code is placed in the same place (in the primary form's Load event handler) in another application.