# How to show cursor immediately on app startup?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, .net-4.0, cursor

My app takes a bit to start because the UI is pretty heavy.  I want to show Cursors.AppWaiting cursor the moment the user double-clicks on the shortcut.  So I pop `Cursor.Current = Cursors.AppStarting;` into the constructor of the main form.  However, when I start the app, the cursor does not change until after the form is loaded.

Is there a way to change the cursor immediately after the user double-clicks the shortcut?

Comment: Windows already does this, displays that cursor for up to 6 seconds.  If it takes longer then you need a splash screen: http://stackoverflow.com/a/393870/17034

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can do the work using a [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and [UseWaitCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.usewaitcursor.aspx) property to change cursor.

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
UseWaitCursor = true;
bw.DoWork += (s, e) =>
{
    //do work.. 
};

bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
   Invoke((Action)(() => UseWaitCursor = false)); 
};
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

After changing the cursor.

Comment: One of the *very few* (IMO) legitimate times to use Application.DoEvents()

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, I was hesitant to place it as an answer as it is one of those answers that someone on a bad day would down vote.

Comment: @Andrew, I can't believe I heard you saying that ;)

Comment: @Halabi I clearly said and emphsized *very few*. Almost every other time I see it mentioned it is a *horrible* idea.

Comment: @Andrew I know what you said mate. I am just happy ;)

Comment: I'm *still* tempted to downvote this, and I'm having a great day. The reason I'm tempted to downvote is because you propose it as if it were "magic code", rather than explaining *why* this approach actually fixes the problem. Mention pumping the message loop to process a `WM_SETCURSOR` message or something that makes it clear this isn't a general fix for all sorts of UI problems, and I might even be tempted to upvote. No one argues that `DoEvents` is useless; they argue that it's misunderstood and almost always used inappropriately. Answers like this do little to curb that unfortunate reality.

Answer (score -1):

Just collapse your MainGrid until the app is loaded

### Converter Reference

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

### XAML ElementReference

```
 Visibility="{Binding Path=IsLoaded, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the OP's question.