# Windows Form App timer to change form

Tags: windows, forms, timer

I'm quite a new guy into coding with C#
And I really want to know how I would change from one form to another one after x amount of seconds.

Like it has a little "Loading screen" which then dissapears and changes in the main form.

I've searched around but couldn't find any solution. Any suggestions would be amazing!

Comment: It is called "splash screen".  Use the [built-in support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392864/splash-screen-waiting-until-thread-finishes/393870#393870) to create one.  Assign the MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime property in the MyApp constructor.

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks.