# c# winform loading screen

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async-await

I want to add a loading form in a function

```
private async void Test()
{
    // 1, show loading form

    await DoTest();

    //2, close loading form
}
```

the loading form need to block the main form, at first, I try to run the form `ShowDialog()`, but it will stop the following function

What's the best idea to do this?

My final solution:

```
private async void Test()
{
    // 1, show loading form
    var loadingScreen = new LoadingForm();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate
    {
        Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            loadingScreen.ShowDialog(App.Views.Forms.RobotActiveView);
        });
    });

    await DoTest();

    //2, close loading form
    Invoke((Action)delegate
    {
        loadingScreen.Close();
    });
}
```

Comment: is the whole point of the loading form to prevent user interaction?

Comment: @AlexW yes, as the download function, loading data and so on...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/393870/366904

Comment: @CodyGray not show the splash screen at startup application. the loading screen used to waiting the "BIG" function

Comment: @CodyGray this is not a duplicate case......

Comment: Looks like the same problem to me. How is it any different that you want to display a splash screen when displaying the main form at startup, versus displaying a splash screen while displaying another form?

Comment: @CodyGray Sorry, maybe my question is not clear. it is NOT for startup form. I just want to show the "Waiting Screen" when user click the button to submit the request.

Comment: You have not yet explained how that is a fundamentally different problem, or why it would require a different solution.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't know why they are the same problem...

Comment: Because I would literally post exactly the same answer as KeithS, except instead of telling you to create the splash screen in the Main method, I'd say to create it in whatever method you run your code. You ask "What's the best way to do this?", and that question is already answered in the duplicate. I do not understand what your problem is.

Comment: @CodyGray Okay, maybe they are the "SAME", I added my final solution. and thx for your information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show loading form and disable current form.

```
this.Enabled = false;

var loadingForm = new LoadingForm();
loadingForm.Show();

...

loadingForm.Close();

this.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Good idea, gives me an inspiration, but my program is MVP, so I will try to disable the form at Presenter.