# How do you implement a C++/CLI splash screen?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, c++-cli

I'm trying to make an application using C++/CLI and being new, I found out that there's not much of an article about C++/CLI splash screens. Question is, how do you make/implement a splash screen in your C++/CLI code?

Comment: You can do the as described here: [Splash Screen waiting until thread finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/393870/7444103) (same thing). Or, you can build your own class, inherit `ApplicationContext`, replace the methods you see in that answer with your own and, in `Main`, instead of running a new instance of a starting Form, you run your ApplicationContext. See the example in [Application.Run(System::Windows::Forms::ApplicationContext^ context)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try the following code to implement splash screen in c++/cli.

Mainform:

```
public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            Thread^ t = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this,&MyForm::StartForm));
            t->Start();
            Thread::Sleep(5000);
            InitializeComponent();
            t->Abort();
            
        
        }
    public:void StartForm()
    {
        Project1::SplashScreen form;
        Application::Run(% form);
    }
```

Result:

[image]