# C# Splash Loading Page

Tags: c#, winforms, load, splash-screen

Im about to start working on a big application (big for me anyway :P) and i was wondering, how do i create a splash page for the program that shows up as soon as the exe is launched and disappears when all of the exe is loaded?

Comment: While your question is kind of valid, I suggest that you forget the splash screen for now and just add it later if the startup time really justifies this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS made this easy if you're using VB.NET. However, you can still make this work in C#. Have a look at [WindowsFormsApplicationBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.aspx).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916/multi-threaded-splash-screen-in-c), too.

Comment: that question you linked me to had the perfect answer. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF then simply load an image into the project, right click > properties, and choose splash screen.  WPF should take care of the rest for you :)