# WPF animated splash screen

Tags: wpf, vb.net, animation, splash-screen

Is it possible to show a splash screen in WPF that has animation.  I want my name of the company and the name of the application to fly in and a progress bar that continously animates.  I Used this example

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/wpf-and-the-splashscreen

to try and get me started but the progress bar doesnt animate?

Also I do have on the progress bar the following property set. IsIndeterminate="True"

I am using vb.net.

Thanks,
spafa9

Comment: The blog post you linked looks like it has everything you need. Does your animation work if you copy it to a new Window in a new project? Do you get any errors? Do you have the splash screen correctly showing up and the only issue is the animation does not play?

Comment: Yes I put it in a new project and just copied the code. The only thing I couldnt get to work was the Private Sub Application_Exit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.ExitEventArgs) Handles Me.Exit ' Container.DisposeAll() End Sub 


Everything comes up right it show it and then shows the main form but doesnt animate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer at the bottom of this question: [Multi-threaded splash screen in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916/multi-threaded-splash-screen-in-c/3296362#3296362)

This is in C#, but it does work with an animated indeterminate progress bar.

Comment: How do I referance the <Application Startup="ApplicationStart"  I am getting that it is not apart of the project or its build action is not a resource. StartupUri="Application_Startup"

Comment: The part I dont know how to convert to vb is this

Comment: var thread = new Thread(() => 
        { 
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke ((Action)(() => new MySplashForm().Show())); 
            Dispatcher.Run(); 
        });

Comment: OK I got a litte farther. The splash screen never shows up but the mainwindow does? 

 Dim SplashThread As New Thread(AddressOf ShowSplash)

        SplashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
        SplashThread.IsBackground = True
        SplashThread.Start()

        ' call synchronous configuration process 
        ' and declare/get reference to "main form" 

        SplashThread.Abort()


        MainWindow = New MainWindow()
        MainWindow.Show()
        MainWindow.Activate()