# Splash screen is pinned to taskbar, main screen shows additional taskbar entry

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, splash-screen, jump-list

In my application, when you pin the installed app to the Taskbar from the Start Menu, and then launch the application from the pinned icon, the splash screen shows as if it is running from the pinned icon but once the main screen shows a new icon is displayed in the taskbar.

It is as if the main window is not tied to the same app as the splash.

If I launch the app from the Start Menu and then pin it from the running icon in the taskbar, it works fine (because at the time that I pinned it, the main window was open).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Disable the Splash Screen's [Form from showing in the taskbar in the first place](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar.aspx)?

```
// before displaying the form
splashScreenForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
splashScreenForm.Show();
```

Comment: I want it to show in the Taskbar because it "does stuff" to start the application. If it doesn't show in the Taskbar it can easily get hidden behind other windows which will cause the use not to notice it is asking for something. Is there no other way to make this work?

Comment: In that case, [try the solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916/multi-threaded-splash-screen-in-c). It's not exactly the same issue, and it definitely is not the same question, but I wonder if the different handling may work in your project's favor compared to the current execution path that your splash screen takes now?