# Display Image at project startup - program.cs?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small Windows Forms project and now Iam looking to display an image at project startup, I mean Program.cs

Is it possible?

```
static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Image MyPrgImage = Image.FromFile("C:\\Temp\\Images\\For_Network.gif");
            ??????

            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
```

Comment: You mean like a splash screen?

Comment: You are looking to create a splash screen. Check this out: http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%23+splash+screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure... Add new `WindowsForm` to your project, call it `SplashImageForm`. Add `PictureBox` control to it, and add the image you want in it. Resize the form, set these `SplashImageForm` properties:

```
FormBorderStyle - None
ShowInTaskBar - false
StartPosition - CenterScreen
```

Then you want to show that form before Form1 and close it after the timeout has expired... Like so for example:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    SplashImageForm f = new SplashImageForm();

    f.Shown += new EventHandler((o,e)=>{
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                f.Invoke(new Action(() => { f.Close(); }));

            });
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();
    });

    Application.Run(f);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

**EDIT** 
Now, there is new thread which blocks on `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)` for 2 seconds, and the main thread is allowed to block on `Application.Run(f)` as it is supposed to, until the `SplashImageForm` isn't closed. So the image gets loaded by the main thread and the GUI is responsive.

When the timeout ends, `Invoke()` method is called so the main thread which is the owner of the form closes it. If this wasn't here, Cross threaded exception would be thrown.

Now the image is shown for 2 secs, and after it Form1 is shown.

Comment: But the problem is picturebox display no problem. But the image is not displaying with picturebox...

Comment: Try now. Check the code again, I edited it to add new thread that will be blocked instead of the old code where the main thread was blocked.

Comment: @Cipi: what I refer to is purely a personal preference ...for instance, rather than fixing the splash screen to 2 seconds, I would have another event, like `Form1.HandleCreated`, that closes the splash screen. Like I said, you're not wrong by any means (I +1 your answer) ...the closing is just personal preference.

Comment: Hey Cipi that looks like a nice example (+1), but Form1 would only be created once the splash screen is closed. So if the creation of Form1 takes a lot of time there would still be a moment where nothing is shown on screen. It would be nice to have Form1 directly shown after SplashImageForm is closed.

Answer (score 3):

You mean a splash screen, right?
Consider adding a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic (if not already done) and then set the [`WindowsFormsApplicationBase.SplashScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.splashscreen.aspx) property.

A few more points:

- Windows Forms doesn't have support for a simple and straight splash screen.
  Even the solution above will take a few seconds until the .net framework is loaded to show the splash screen.
- See this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916/multi-threaded-splash-screen-in-c) for further examples and important remarks.
- See this [CodeProject.com sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/prettygoodsplashscreen.aspx) for a custom solution

Comment: @IAbstract can you explain why not? I agree that it seem weird, but you also add a reference to other DLLs just to use their features. VisualBasic.dll is maintained by MS and an integral part of the .net framework, so I don't see any problem with this.

Comment: See @Cipi's answer ...that doesn't use the reference. I don't necessarily agree with the process he uses for closing the form, but it isn't incorrect.

Comment: @IAbstract: Whats wrong with form closing in my code? It is thread safe, and it closes the form... :)

Comment: @IAbstract: Would like to see your idea... Post it as a comment here and I will add it to my answer with a reference to you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You would need a simple form, perhaps with a PictureBox, to loadd and display the image. Then remove it once your main form is loaded.

Comment: But the problem is picturebox display no problem. But the image is not displaying with picturebox...

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a windows form(let the name of form be imgsplash) & from option set following:-

FormBorderStyle - None
ShowInTaskBar - false
StartPosition - CenterScreen

in this form set background image[image which you want to show at startup of application]

--now in program.cs add folloing steps:-

```
       static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        imgsplash f = new imgsplash();
        f.Show();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        f.Close();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```