# Label inside form(splash screen) not displaying

Tags: c#, winforms, splash-screen

I have made a simple splash screen in a C# winforms application. The problem is that the form shows up, but I have a label inside my form which doesn't show up. A black box is shown where the label should be displayed.

I have made a Form, keeping the properties `ShowInTaskbar=False`, and `FormBorderStyle=None` . The form's `opacity` is set to 50%. Then I have a label inside this form, with `text='Loading...'` .

I have used this code to show the form:

```
splashScreen splash=new splashScreen();
splash.Show();
```

I've used `splash.Close()` to close it when I want to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely because your app is too busy loading to render the label. For a splash screen to be responsive while the app is loading it needs to be multi threaded. You can find information on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916/multi-threaded-splash-screen-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's just a label control i.e. no user or program interaction required, I found the simplest way was to create a temporary label, scan the image into a jpeg, open the jpeg and save to a bitmap. Then all you have to do on your splash screen is to create a panel of a suitable size, import the bitmap into it as a background, set its layout as stretch, then it will display in the splash screen.