# Is this possible to do in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I don't know what to call it so i can't search google or anything for this.

My question is:

How can i make something like this in C#?

[image: How can you do this?]

Or is this not possible in C#?

Like not use a `Form` but just do something like a `PictureBox` when the program starts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can hide the border of your form, add a picturebox to it and make the background of the form transparent...

Comment: It's called a splash screen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916/multi-threaded-splash-screen-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a splash screen and it's very much possible in C#.

It's probably just a transparent form with images and placeholder labels.

Comment: It is not, note the drop-shadow.  You'll only get that from SetWindowRgn(), exposed as the Form.Region property.

Comment: You can add a drop shadow to a form. It's all still possible. The main problem is performance really, you want it up faster than the rest of the application.

Comment: I tried doing a 0% Opacity on my form but it makes the label that Opacity too, How do i change this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with images and a transparent background on the form which suffices for a typical splash screen.

However if you need to make an irregular form where you can interact with contents behind the bounding rectangle of the form [you'll need to get more creative](http://www.vcskicks.com/custom_shape_form_region.php).

Answer (score 0):

There's a blogpost about the creator and what he used for the splashscreen, you could refer to this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/11/11/behind-the-scenes-splash-screen.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**`VS2010`** runs as a **`WPF`** application. WPF supports full alpha channel transparency, so the non-rectangular splash screens will always look better when using WPF than when using winforms

Try this one http://www.vcskicks.com/splash-screen.php where you can create custom splash screens.

Comment: @Dozer- we look better than what you ask here..we try to give the best we have.

Comment: You didn't even answer my question with a WinForms answer, you answer it with a WPF answer. It doesn't help me at all.