# How do you open a start form and close it after some instructions are displayed?

Tags: c#, forms

I have a form(`f1`) that needs to run some instructions before opening another one(`f2`), and when it ends must close. I set in `program.cs` `Application.Run(new f1());`and at the end of f1 istructions I wrote

```
f2 f = new f2();
f.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

but it doesn't close, just goes in background.

Comment: Sounds like you're misusing forms. Why don't you move that code out to a class and call that class before doing `Application.Run(new f2())` and skip the first pointless form?

Comment: Do you mean like a splash screen? Like Outlook opens when loading, and then getting the user to click OK before loading the application?

Comment: yes @DominicZukiewicz .. i would like to obtain something like that or visual studio starting form

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil 'cause in the first form i load data from files to a dgv and I made the start form with a progress to hide all the loading process

Comment: @user3547175 It sounded like you were using the first form just as a placeholder for code, which wouldn't be the proper use of a form. I see you're going for a splashscreen though. What you want is to display `f1` (splashscreen) while you load data and when the data is done loading you want to close `f1` and display `f2`?

Comment: @user3547175: Have a look at this question too. It seems to have what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4994912/128444

Comment: `f1` splash screen and `f2` is the main form, need to close f1 after loading istructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything should work the way you have it but hide f1 and display f2 this way:

```
this.Hide();
var frm2 = new f2();
frm2.Closed += (sender, args) => this.Close();
frm2.Show();
```

To give a more detailed answer:

```
public class Form1() : Form
{
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        // this is where you can load your data from file
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(
        object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) 
    {
        this.Hide();
        var frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.Closed += (s, a) => this.Close();
        frm2.Show();
    }
}
```

So `Form1` will start to load data using a background worker. When the data is loaded, the `BackgroundWorker` will fire the `RunWorkerCompleted` event. That event handler will hide `Form1` instead of closing it, create `Form2`, add a handler for form2's `Closed` event so that closing `Form2` will stop your application, and then shows `Form2`.